# Can I reference a function created earlier?

Tags: php

So I have a php file, something like this

```
<html>
<head>
<title><?php
function demo1() {
  return date("d-m-Y");
}
echo demo1();
?></title>
</head>
<body>
<?php 
echo "Today's Date is".demo1();
?>
```

Would I be able to do this or do I have to declare the function again?

Comment: Yes, as long as you declared the function before using it or **included** if declared in other file

Comment: Functions (subroutines in general) are one of the basic building blocks of programming that facilitate reuse of code. As long as the function is defined before you're calling it, you can use it without having to redeclare it.